# VBScript hanging on CopyFile operation

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write a function to compare date modified on the server file to the client's and overwrite the client file if it is older. This runs as part of a Group Policy startup script. The tmp flies are created as a debugging step to see where the code is getting stuck. copyfile.tmp is created but copydone.tmp is not. None of the files are read-only, and this runs under the local SYSTEM context, which has all the access it needs.

The files all exist. I've successfully copied the server file to the client earlier in the script if the client didn't have one. (`oFSO` is a file system object, `strWinTemp` is the system's temp directory in Windows; defined earlier)

```
'Replace clientfile if older than servfile
Sub GetNewerFile(clientfile,servfile)
    Dim dtmLocalDate
    Dim dtmServerDate
    Dim oLocalFile
    Dim oServerFile
    Set oLocalFile = oFSO.GetFile(clientfile)
    dtmLocalDate = oLocalFile.DateLastModified
    Set oServerFile = oFSO.GetFile(servfile)
    dtmServerDate = oServerFile.DateLastModified

    If Not oFSO.FileExists(strWinTemp & "\" & "getnewerfile.tmp") Then oFSO.CreateTextFile(strWinTemp & "\" & "getnewerfile.tmp")
    If DateDiff("d", dtmServerDate, dtmLocalDate) > 0 Then
        'dtmServerDate is more recent than dtmLocalDate, comparison by "day"
        If Not oFSO.FileExists(strWinTemp & "\" & "copyfile.tmp") Then oFSO.CreateTextFile(strWinTemp & "\" & "copyfile.tmp")
        oFSO.CopyFile oServerFile, oLocalFile, 1
        If Not oFSO.FileExists(strWinTemp & "\" & "copydone.tmp") Then oFSO.CreateTextFile(strWinTemp & "\" & "copydone.tmp")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

I replaced the lines between the DateDiff check and End Sub with this:

```
If oFSO.FileExists(clientfile) then oFSO.DeleteFile(clientfile)
oFSO.CopyFile servfile, clientfile, TRUE
```

Comment: Since VBScript interprets 0 as `False` and non-zero values as `True` in a boolean context (like the `Overwrite` parameter of `CopyFile`) it's clearly not possible that this change would resolve the problem described in your question.

Comment: Right.
I still don't understand why oFSO.Copyfile oSrv oLocal didn't work, with or without the optional "TRUE" at the end.
Just feeding the filespec (path + filename) works just fine and I don't need to create more objects.

Note: my biggest issue here was that I was calling the function with the parameters in the WRONG ORDER. D'OH!